# Arduino Nano IoT 33 Char Array size constraints

Tags: wifi, array, memory, arduino-nano-33-iot

I would like to save data that I am receiving from API calls in a char array. The problem is that the data is around 80 kB, and my Arduino IoT 33 only has 32 kB of memory.

It will save data in a char array up to 25000 bytes, but when I go to 30000 bytes or above the Arduino freezes. When I copy-paste the entire data to a char array without specifying the size it works fine, but when receiving data over the API in chunks of 10 kB it won't save the entire 80 kB. Is there a way around this?

Comment: why do you want to store all that data? process it right away.

Comment: well, it is basically a hexadecimal array to update an E-Ink Display. I need all of it at the same time.

Comment: then use a SD card or save it to flash memory (if it is not to many writes)

Comment: well, my Arduino has a CPU Flash Memory of 256KB can use that somehow?

Comment: you can, but it has only 10000 writes

Comment: wait so what do you mean by 1000 writes? Can't I save 80kb in CPU flash?

Comment: you can but flash memories have limited count of write-erase cycles

Comment: I will be updating my display probably 5 to 6 times a day. That should be enough right?

Comment: I will try that. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: what do you mean by `hexadecimal array`? ... are you storing text, not bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flash memory of the SAMD21 MCU used on the Nano 33 IoT, if you don't write too often. Flash memories have a limited count of write-erase cycles. It is guarantied for 10000 writes.

For Arduino SAMD boards like the Nano 33 IoT you can use the [FlashStorage library](https://github.com/cmaglie/FlashStorage). The library is in the Library Manager.